# PHP date function producing incorrect result

Tags: php, date

Am currently running the following PHP version on my laptop

```
PHP Version 7.0.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

Problem is when i run the below piece of code

```
echo date('b e, Y', strtotime('2013-02-01'));
```

i get the following output

```
b Africa/Nairobi, 2013
```

and yet it is supposed to produce the following output

```
Feb 1, 2013
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: `e` prints the timezone identifier and there is no `b` format character.  If you want the abbreviated month and the day of month, use `M j, Y`.  http://php.net/date

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/date - as you can see, the output is as expected. To get your desired output, you need the `M j, Y` format.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for documentation

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to read [the documentation for the date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) again.  There is no `b` option that I'm aware of and:

> ***e*** - Timezone identifier (added in PHP 5.1.0)

To achieve that result you'd want:

```
echo date('M j, Y', strtotime('2013-02-01'));
```

> ***M*** - A short textual representation of a month, three letters
>
> ***j*** - Day of the month without leading zeros

Comment: maybe i have gotten to used to mysql's date_format letter representations and i was just transferring them over to php

Comment: ah that makes sense - I was wondering where you got that format from

Answer (score 3):

Try simply this `M j, Y`, See more formatting at official php documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
 echo date('M j, Y', strtotime('2013-02-01'));
```

**M**   A short textual representation of a month, three letters e.g **Jan through Dec**

**j**   Day of the month without leading zeros e.g **1 to 31**

**Y**   A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits   e.g: **1999 or 2003**

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/97Uvq

Comment: I think I beat you by a few seconds but we can call it a tie :-)

Comment: Yes, you beat me. While I was posing,  I saw "A new answer..." :) so you won. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
B (not b)   Swatch Internet time    000 through 999,
e   Timezone identifier (added in PHP 5.1.0)

You try code :

```
echo date('M j, Y', strtotime('2013-02-01'));
```

Out put:

```
Feb 1, 2013
```